# The `message` field value is not set in `CustomError` class in NodeJS with the classical inheritance through the function-constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, prototypal-inheritance, javascript-inheritance

This case works just fine:

```
class CustomError2015 extends Error {
    constructor(message) {
        super(message); // here the message is set correctly
        console.log("Message: " + this.message); 
    }
}

throw new CustomError2015("ECMAScript 2015 class inheritance");
```

I expected that this one would work the same way, but it didn't:

```
function CustomError(message){
    Error.call(this, message); // here the message IS NOT set
    console.log("Message: " + this.message); 
}
CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
CustomError.prototype.constructor = CustomError;

throw new CustomError("CustomError function-like inheritance");
```

I'm wondering why? 
I there something wrong with my code or what?

<sup>* [These code samples' playground.](https://runkit.com/develax/stackoverflow-custom-error-constructor)</sup>

Comment: Builtins like `Error` cannot be extended (easily) in ES5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built in types (`Error`, `Array`) are *exotic*, that means that their constructor is not normal, and the objects of their instance are not normal, they are special internal objects. Therefore this:

```
  Error.call(this, message)
```

does not work as `Error` has to return an exotic object, while `this` is a regular object, and the engine can't convert one into the other. Therefore it returns a new exotic error (which you ignore in your code):

```
  let exotic = Error.call(this);
  exotic === this // false
```

The message gets set on that exotic object, and not on `this`.

That works in classes as `super(....)` gets called before you can access `this`, and therefore `this` can be the exotic object, you cannot replicate that behaviour without classes.

[read on](http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html)

Comment: Since when are errors exotic? They don't have any weird internal slots, do they? Sure, `Error.call` does not work, but that doesn't have anything to do with exotic vs. non-exotic objects.

Comment: @bergi okay maybe not exotic, but *special* ? :)

Comment: What's interesting is that I read about it not so long ago :)